# get resource id from the position of listitem in android

Tags: android

i want to get the resource id or the resource name from the position of selected list item in android .

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       int position=0;
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_previous:
                int position =item.getItemId();
                if(position!=0){
                   position=position-1;
                }
    }
```

now i want to get the resouce id or resource name for this decremented position variable .please help me solve this problem

Comment: But you can use simply switch case for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **item.getItemId(position)** ==> return *id* of *item* at *position*

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a list of all your item and select item with the position

Answer (score 0):

i think you need name of item that `id = position-1;`

so simply you can declare your menu item with new id like:

```
MenuItem newItem = findViewById(position-1);
```

now you can get anything from your `newItem`.